# add title to a dataframe, save it then read it in and display result not what I expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe that I read in and display. Then I add a title to the dataframe. I save the titled dataframe, then read it in and display it but the result is NOT what I expected. I repeats the title in each column. Code is shown below.

```
# read in a simple dataframe
csvpath=r'C:\Users\tfuser\Documents\2023 Taxes\test1.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(csvpath)
display(df)
# add a title to the dataframe and display the result
text='  TITLE'
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[text], df.columns])
display(df)
# save the titled dataframe, then read it in and display it
save_path=r'C:\Users\tfuser\Documents\2023 Taxes\saved.csv'
df.to_csv(save_path, index=False)
recovered_df=pd.read_csv(save_path)
display(recovered_df)
```

The resultant the outputs are shown below:

```
A   B   C
0   A1  B1  C1
1   A2  B2  C2
2   A3  B3  C3


TITLE
A   B   C
0   A1  B1  C1
1   A2  B2  C2
2   A3  B3  C3


  TITLE TITLE.1 TITLE.2
0   A     B     C
1   A1    B1    C1
2   A2    B2    C2
3   A3    B3    C3
```

I know it has something to do with the muti index but I don't know how to fix it to get a single title as shown in the second output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the number of headers to use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(save_path, header=[0, 1])  # 2 header lines
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    TITLE        
        A   B   C
0      A1  B1  C1
1      A2  B2  C2
2      A3  B3  C3

>>> df.columns
MultiIndex([('  TITLE', 'A'),
            ('  TITLE', 'B'),
            ('  TITLE', 'C')],
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[text], df.columns])
```

With:

```
df.columns = [text + col for col in df.columns]
```

The latter modifies the column names by concatenating them with the text, while the former creates a MultiIndex structure with separate levels.  Not what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
        'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
        'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
    A   B   C
0  A1  B1  C1
1  A2  B2  C2
2  A3  B3  C3
```

To save a title process as follows (key is saving it apart as the first csv-row):

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

data = {'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
        'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
        'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

savePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "dataframe.csv")
# Save the titled dataframe in the current directory with the column headers
df.to_csv(savePath, index=False, header=True)

# Define a title for the dataframe
title = 'My DataFrame Title'

# Save the dataframe to a CSV file with the title as the first row
with open(savePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(title + '\n')
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=True, sep=',')

# Read the CSV file back into a dataframe and display it
df2 = pd.read_csv(savePath)
print(df2)
```

df2 :

```
      My DataFrame Title
A  B                   C
A1 B1                 C1
A2 B2                 C2
A3 B3                 C3
```